# Getting (x,y) positions of an object from its text

Tags: vbscript, qtp, uft14

How to get the positions x,y of an element from its text using UFT?
I tried using `getTOProperty(x)` but it doesn't work for me

Comment: What kind of object (web/java/etc.)? Are you able to identify the object (click it)?

Answer (score 1):

**GetRoProperty** - is a built method used to retrieve the runtime value of an object property.
So if you have a variabled named X, you can do X = whateverobject.getROProperty("x").
Same for y.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but what I am searching for is to know the position X (or Y)  of a text not an object

Comment: A text field or label is an object, everything is an object.  Whether it's a javastatictext, javaobject, javabutton, etc.  What exactly is the object you are looking to get the coordinates from?